# Как вставить пустое значение (NULL) в поле типа "datetime" в SQL таблице?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, datetime

Есть в строке пустой элемент '', при запросе в бд PostgreSQL, в этом месте находится тип timestamp. При простой передаче, выдает ошибку - "Неверный формат timestamp". Нужно передать пустое значение в бд.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо пустой строки передать `None`

Comment: @MaxU, запрос берет значение из списка по индексу из файла, и список нельзя поменять. None мне не помог, я уже пытался

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (__«почему этот код не работает?»__) должны включать желаемое поведение, _конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код_ для её воспроизведения __прямо в вопросе__. Вопросы __без явного описания проблемы__ бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MaxU, дополнил

Comment: @MaxU не текстового, а csv

Comment: отлично! можете привести ту же строку из вопроса, но точно в таком виде как она сохранена в CSV файле?

Comment: @MaxU, добавил в вопрос

Comment: Есть ли в вашем CSV файле заголовок - первая строка с именами полей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно преобразовывать тип данных в списке записей и передавать его в качестве параметров.

Данные:

```
data = [
 ['20190822095033',
  '79525364123',
  '258',
  'remote',
  'false',
  '',
  'suspend',
  '',
  'mobile_portal',
  '158681014',
  'USSD',
  '258',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  ''],
 ['',
  '222',
  '333',
  'remote',
  'false',
  '',
  'suspend',
  '',
  '???????',
  '???????',
  'USSD',
  '444',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '']
]
```

Решение:

```
from datetime import datetime as DT           

def parse_dt(s, fmt="%Y%m%d%H%M%S"):
    if not s:
        return None
    return DT.strptime(s, fmt)

qry = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES({})".format(", ".join(["%s"] * 16))
records = list(map(lambda x: [parse_dt(x[0])] + x[1:], data))
cursor.executemany(qry, records)
```

---

вид данных после обработки:

```
In [64]: records
Out[64]:
[[datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 22, 9, 50, 33),   # <---- NOTE!
  '79525364123',
  '258',
  'remote',
  'false',
  '',
  'suspend',
  '',
  'mobile_portal',
  '158681014',
  'USSD',
  '258',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  ''],
 [None,    # <---- NOTE!
  '222',
  '333',
  'remote',
  'false',
  '',
  'suspend',
  '',
  '???????',
  '???????',
  'USSD',
  '444',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '']]
```

---

Сгенерированный SQL запрос:

```
In [67]: print(qry)
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего вставить данные из CSV файла в SQL таблицу при помощи модуля [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

conn = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@host:port/dbname")
(pd.read_csv(r"/path/to/file.csv")
   .to_sql("table_name", conn, if_exists="append", index=False))
```

Comment: Забыл добавить, данные стоят не по порядку как в базе и данных меньше чем колонок в бд

Comment: @Demoralization, если хотите работающий и эффективный ответ - укажите в вопросе структуру PostgreSQL таблицы (лучше всего `CREATE TABLE ...` statement), первые 3-4 строки CSV файла и список и порядок полей из CSV файла, которые надо вставить в таблицу

Comment: Настоятельно советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)